# python client sever using multi threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am making a client-server program in python using multi threading but when 2 clients send data to the server. It can only reply to the 2nd client can someone help to solve it, its my project requirement to do this in multi threading

code :

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

host =''

port=888
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("socket created ")

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error:
    print("BINDING FAILED")
    sys.exit()
print("socket hai bounded ")


s.listen(10)#/upto 10 people can be connet

print("socket is ready")

def clientthread(conn):
    welcomemessage="WELCOME TO SERVER TYPE SOMETHING AND HIT ENTER "
    conn.send(welcomemessage.encode())
    while True:
        data=conn.recv(1024)
        reply="OK." +data.decode()
        if not data:
            break;
        print(reply)

        reply1=input("your message :")
        conn.sendall(reply1.encode())
    conn.close()


while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("conneted with " + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,))
s.close()
```

Comment: `data.decode()` why do you do this?

Comment: this is the server side it accepts connection from the client in the while loop in the end conn,addr=s.accept()

Comment: data.decode() is use to convert byte to string

Comment: Apologies, the rest of the code was available, just needed scrolling :(